# Why is client network-background-render split into one frame jobs?

Tags: rendering, network

When I'm trying to render a Clientjob on Networkrender by shell in background ( blender -b job1.blend -a ) The Job will be split into single 1 frame jobs on the Network Rendering system. No Clustering, no dispatching, no Network rendering.

If I do the same job by GUI, everything is fine! 
( Job will be one single Job, will be clustered, and dispatched to different machines )

I'm trying to understand where's the difference between rendering by command line, or GUI?

[image: Hope the Image makes it clearer]